# Material baking as black?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, texture-baking

I'm not sure why I can't bake this. I've unwrapped it, I tried baking it as glossy when it had the Principled BSDF, deleted the Principled BSDF and tried baking again, but every time it baked as just a black texture. Does anybody know how to fix this? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer! Apparently it won't bake when I have an HDRI, so I ended up deleting the HDRI and bringing back the default world background, and it worked! :)